# Can I map as alb with root domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I understand we can map AWS ALB URL to `CNAME` and then use with subdomain. Route53 provides Alias which allows us to map ALB URL to root domain, say `example.com`, Does others DNS providers have this options? Say GoDaddy or Network Solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The alias feature is something that is available in [AWS Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) only. The alias does the mapping internally and assigns the IP address. If you do nslookup for alias you will surely get an aws ip address. for other dns provider to be aware of what aws is assigning ip address to an ELB is not possible until and unless both business want to do so.

But there is hope! and this can be achieved by using [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) and [AWS Cloudwatch Scheduled Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)

You would need to query the IP address for your ELB and then use Godaddy's API to update your DNS entry over there, you can set an interval like every 5 minutes to do this.

Comment: What will happen if the IP get changed in between the interval? Site will not be accessible

Comment: That depends on the interval you set, But yes as we are looking for way arounds you may have to deal with these kind of things